# How does SQL Server store these Unicode characters into a column that is VARCHAR(MAX) and not NVARCHAR(MAX)

Tags: sql-server, unicode, utf-8

I have some data which I believe is Unicode and seeing what happens when I store it into my database column which is of `VARCHAR(MAX)` datatype.

[image]

And here's the source, from the file which is UTF-8...

```
looking for that &#8216;X&#8217; and &#8226; 3 large bedrooms with 2 ensuites and &#8226; Main bedroom with ensuite &amp; surround with plantation shutters`
```

and using the Visual Studio debugger:

[image]

=> so 2x apostrophes and 2x bullets.

I thought SQL Server can only store Unicode if the column is of type `NVARCHAR`?

I'm assuming my source data is not Unicode and therefore, I totally suck at all this Unicode/UTF-8 stuff :(

Comment: It looks like hex code and not unicode. you can check http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm. unicode are usually represented as ? in varchar colums. also check https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f7ed0f1a-14e2-4c7d-ab0a-405e48f8b7e1/inserting-unicode-text-into-varchar-column-?forum=transactsql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought SQL Server can only store Unicode if the column is of type NVARCHAR?

That's correct. As far as I can guess from your example, it is not storing Unicode. Probably it is storing bytes encoded in Windows code page 1252, which would be the default encoding for a Western install of SQL Server.

Code page 1252 [happens to include](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) mappings for characters `‘`, `’` and `•`, so those characters can be safely stored. But step outside that limited repertoire and you'll start losing characters.